# How to configure NGINX in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, devops, nginx-ingress, amazon-elb

I have set up k8s cluster in AWS ec2 instances with 1 parent and 2 child nodes using kops.

Deployed 2 services and running with LoadBalancer service type in browser.
Now I installed NGINX but through LB ip not able to hit my service. It is giving `504 GATEWAY_TIME_OUT` exception. Googled it but no success, Where am I going wrong? Here is my sample code...[AWS FREE ACCOUNT]

deployment.yml

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    app: $APP_NAME
  name: $APP_NAME
  namespace: $NAMESPACE
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: $APP_NAME  
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: $APP_NAME        
    spec:
      imagePullSecrets:
      - name: $IMG_PULL_SECRET   
      containers:
      - image: $IMAGE_REG/$APP_NAME:$IMAGE_TAG
        name: $APP_NAME
        imagePullPolicy: Always  

        ports:
        - containerPort: ${CONTAINER_PORT}
          protocol: TCP
        env:
          - name: spring.cloud.config.uri
            value: 'http://config-server-service'
```

service.yml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    app: $APP_NAME
  name: $APP_NAME
  namespace: $NAMESPACE
spec:
  type: $SERVICE_TYPE
  #type: $SERVICE_TYPE
  ports:
  - port: 80
    targetPort: ${CONTAINER_PORT}
    protocol: TCP
  selector:
    app: $APP_NAME
```

ingress.yml

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ${APP_NAME}
  namespace: $NAMESPACE
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/affinity: cookie
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/session-cookie-name: JSESSIONID
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-passthrough: "false"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "false"
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
    kubernetes.io/ingress.allow-http: "true"
#    kubernetes.io/ingress.global-static-ip-name: "my-gateway"
spec:
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
        - path: /${APP_NAME}
          backend:
            serviceName: ${APP_NAME}
            servicePort: 80
```

Comment: Hi @Joe, not a k8s experienced here, but 502 from LB means the backend service is not responding to its requests. Either the nginx service is not listening in the configured port (wrong port, service is not running, etc) or if configured, a health check is failing from LB to backend service, or backend application is not running nor responding. Also I'd check EC2 instances security groups just in case inbound traffic is not allowed. Hope it helps.

Comment: @marianogg9: It is working fine with loadbalancer ip. inbound traffic is allowed http. and giving 504 error. No luck yet.

Comment: have you tried to hit nginx directly to node's IP? sorry about the confusion, but what do you mean with "it is working fine with LB ip"?

Comment: yes tried and there only gives 504 error, and $SERVICE_TYPE=LoadBalancer and dynamic LB ip is generated for that service.using this ip i am able to access but with nginx ingress ip not able to.